# spatially explicit longitudinal categorical change response to predictor variables

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, panel-data, many-categories

I'm doing a land use/land cover change (LULCC) analysis with annual data spanning 10 years. The land cover class pixels change annually (ie A -> B -> D -> A). There are 5 nominal response categories. I have both continuous and categorical predictor variables. I'm trying to find a good way to analyze the change from different classes across time and how the predictor variables influence that change. I'm more interested in the influence of the predictor variables than forecasting into the future, which most LULCC analyses seems to focus on.

I've looked into Pontius' work from Clark University, but his analyses use land cover changes that are determinant while mine are dynamic. A recent paper from Gaur et al. 2020 suggests some models (ie multilayer perceptron - markov model), but I'm not sure if those are appropriate for my situation nor do I know how to apply those in R. Would just a GLMM work in this situation or maybe a model-based multivariate approach?

Example data: [image: Example Data]

What would be the best analysis to capture the dynamic class changes, annual variation, and influence of predictor variables?

Answer (score 0):

After digging, the solution I landed on was to use a multinomial logistic regression for analysis.